# RPY2 RuntimeError: "No environment variable R_HOME could be found, calling the command 'R RHOME' does not return anything..."

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I am running Python 2.7 on Windows 7. First, I installed R and RTools, and changed the following environment variables:

```
RHOME: C:\Program Files\R\R-2.15.2
R_HOME: C:\Program Files\R\R-2.15.2
R_USER: C:\Users\username\Documents
```

And appended the following directories to PATH:

```
C:\Program Files\R\R-2.15.\bin\i386; C:\Rtools\bin
```

Next, I installed RPy2 through a [binary executable here.](https://bitbucket.org/breisfeld/rpy2_w32_fix/issue/1/binary-installer-for-win32)

When running RPY2 through Python I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 254, in run_nodebug
  File "C:\Python27\blaise automation.py", line 14, in <module>
    import rpy2.robjects as robjects
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    import rpy2.rinterface as rinterface
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rpy2\rinterface\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    "or install the win32 package.")
RuntimeError: No environment variable R_HOME could be found, calling the command 'R RHOME' does not return anything, and unable to import win32api or win32con, both of which being needed to retrieve where is R from the registry. You should either specify R_HOME or install the win32 package.
```

I've been working on this for HOURS.  Does anybody have any idea how to resolve it?

My code:

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
import pywin

def main():
     robjects.r("require(foreign)")
```

Comment: I installed `pywin` through pip using `pip install pywin` and it was successful.  However, when I do `import pywin` it says no such module.  I tried downloading the 2.7 binary, but the executable cannot locate `Python 2.7`

Comment: Are the lib folders 'site-packages' and 'win32' in your sys path? If not, try appending them in your script like: sys.path.append("...blabla\lib\site-packages")

Comment: The rpy2 binary you downloaded and installed is quite old. Try getting it from Christoph Gohlke's site (see the doc http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.3/html/overview.html#download )

Comment: I swear I went to that website a million times, and each time there was a message that said RPY2 would not be assembled because of "technical or legal reasons", but I see it now...